# Boot stuck on Dell logo after changing GPU, Secure Boot enabled

Tags: uefi, gpu, secure-boot

I have recently bought and installed an AMD RX Radeon 6600, and now my computer gets stuck at the Dell logo and I cannot get to the BIOS or anything else. After investigating, I found that if I disable Secure Boot the computer will boot just fine. The problem with this is I was planning on upgrading to Windows 11 after installing the new GPU, and now I can't do that, and Windows has forgotten my login PIN because TPM gets disabled along with Secure Boot.

I seem to remember the last time I changed a hardware component I needed to disable Secure Boot, go through a process to sign my hardware, do something with (U)EFI, and then enable Secure Boot again, but I cannot for the life of me remember what that process was or if it is even real.

FYI: My drive is partitioned in GPT. My system booted and worked just fine with Secure Boot enabled before changing the GPU and boots and works just fine with Secure Boot enabled if I put the old GPU back in. So I do think it has something to do with the hardware being signed/recognized by Secure Boot.

What do I have to do to get my new GPU to work with Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: I'd guess this is something with `$ man mokutil` involved, but i have no experience there... sorry.

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS to the latest version yet?

Comment: @Mastaxx I didn't update my BIOS because I was afraid I would brick my computer, but I finally bit the bullet and updated the BIOS. Sure enough, the BIOS version was released before my new GPU was. Updating the BIOS fixed everything. I feel so dumb. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can give you the points. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BIOS Update should fix the issue with the GPU causing it to freeze at splash screen.

Thanks,
Mastaxx